# OCaml : Unbound Module.function value

Tags: ocaml

I'm new to OCaml and I am a little confused about Modules.

I tried to implement a really simple test but I can't compile it...

Here are the files (I'm on Linux by the way) :

**main.ml**

```
let main () =
  if ((Array.length Sys.argv) > 2 && int_of_string Sys.argv.(1) > 1 && int_of_string Sys.argv.(2) > 1)
  then
    begin
      Printf.printf "Args = %d && %d\n" (int_of_string Sys.argv.(1)) (int_of_string Sys.argv.(2));
      Laby.initLaby (int_of_string Sys.argv.(1)) (int_of_string Sys.argv.(2))
    end
  else
    Printf.printf "Usage : ./test x y n"

let _ = main ()
```

**Laby.ml**

```
let initLaby (x : int) (y : int) =
  let testCell = Cell.initCell 0 1 in
  begin
    Printf.printf "Init Laby with X(%d) / Y(%d)\n" x y;
    Cell.printCell testCell;
  end
```

**Cell.ml**

```
module type CELL =
  sig
    type  t

    val initCell : int -> int -> t
    val printCell : t ->  unit
  end

module Cell : CELL =
  struct
    type t = (int * int)

    let initCell (x : int) (y : int) =
      (x, y)

    let printCell (x, y) =
      Printf.printf "Cell -> X(%d) / Y(%d)\n" x y

  end
```

**Cell.mli**

```
module type CELL =
  sig
    type  t

    val initCell : int -> int -> t
    val printCell : t ->  unit
  end

module Cell : CELL
```

And here is the **Makefile** :

```
NAME =  test


ML =    Cell.ml  \
    Laby.ml  \
    main.ml


MLI =   Cell.mli


CMI = $(MLI:.mli=.cmi)
CMO = $(ML:.ml=.cmo)
CMX = $(ML:.ml=.cmx)


OCAMLDPE = ocamldep
CAMLFLAGS = -w Aelz -warn-error A
OCAMLC = ocamlc $(CAMLFLAGS)
OCAMLOPT = ocamlopt $(CAMLFLAGS)
OCAMLDOC = ocamldoc -html -d $(ROOT)/doc


all:        .depend $(CMI) $(NAME)

byte:       .depend $(CMI) $(NAME).byte


$(NAME):    $(CMX)
        @$(OCAMLOPT) -o $@ $(CMX)
        @echo "[OK] $(NAME) linked"

$(NAME).byte:   $(CMO)
        @$(OCAMLC) -o $@ $(CMO)
        @echo "[OK] $(NAME).byte linked"

%.cmx:      %.ml
        @$(OCAMLOPT) -c $<
        @echo "[OK] [$<] builded"

%.cmo:      %.ml
        @$(OCAMLC) -c $<
        @echo "[OK] [$<] builded"

%.cmi:      %.mli
        @$(OCAMLC) -c $<
        @echo "[OK] [$<] builded"

documentation:  $(CMI)
        @$(OCAMLDOC) $(MLI)
        @echo "[OK] Documentation"


re:     fclean all


clean:
        @/bin/rm -f *.cm* *.o .depend *~
        @echo "[OK] clean"


fclean:     clean
        @/bin/rm -f $(NAME) $(NAME).byte
        @echo "[OK] fclean"


.depend:
        @/bin/rm -f .depend
        @$(OCAMLDPE) $(MLI) $(ML) > .depend
        @echo "[OK] dependencies"
```

Here is the output of the Makefile :

```
[OK] dependencies
[OK] [Cell.mli] builded
[OK] [Cell.ml] builded
File "Laby.ml", line 3, characters 17-30:
Error: Unbound value Cell.initCell
Makefile:47: recipe for target 'Laby.cmx' failed
make: *** [Laby.cmx] Error 2
```

I think it's a compilation error, since it seems to not found the Cell module, but I can't make it works...
What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `.ml` file serves as its own module. You seem to have module `Cell` inside `cell.ml` which is double. You would have to address that function as `Cell.Cell.initCell`. Or `open Cell` in `laby.ml`. Also, I think `.ml` file names are conventionally lowercase? Aside: why does `make` output wrong english?

Comment: Thanks, it works !
Are there any way to avoid this double (apart open Cell) ?
And you are right, the file names should be in lowercase, I messed up with C++...
(And the Makefile is from my school lesson's sources, I didnt't see the wrong english...)

Comment: yes, you can make the file cell.ml directly contain the body of the module Cell, and cell.mli contain the body of the signature CELL. (i.e. without struct..end and sig..end respectively). the only difference is that you don't give a name (CELL) explicitly to the module type. such a name is generally needed only when CELL serves as the input to a functor. english: 'builded'->'built' .

Comment: Oh ok, I will try that ! Thanks ! (and for correcting wrong English ^^')

Comment: also, since all types and values are listed in CELL, this means you are not restricting the interface to the module Cell in any way. In this case you can just leave away the file cell.mli completely; the signature is then inferred automatically.

Comment: I read about that, but  it's only a simple example. I will add more values in Cell so I will leave this .mli. But thanks anyway !